# PIE не верно располагает элементы на странице в IE7.

Tags: веб-программирование, html, internet-explorer, css, javascript

Блок со скруглением перемещается отдельно от своих родителей и детей, в то время как родители и дети элемента со скруглением держатся вместе и правильно позиционируются относительно друг-друга.Как решить проблему?

Comment: @player0k, http://codepen.io/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать -pie-poll: true.
Вообще, доля ИЕ7 в рунете около 1го процента, я бы просто порекомендовал отключить для него pie.